# GetPinnableReference Implementation that Pins Underlying String

Tags: .net, pointers, unsafe, c#-7.3

I am trying to implement the new pattern introduced in C# 7.3 that supports pinning of custom types using `fixed` statement. [See article on the Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement)

I am however concerned that in the code below I am returning a pointer to the string, and then *leaving the `fixed` scope*. Of course, this whole routine will be used by a "parent" `fixed` statement that will be "fixing" my custom type, however I am not sure if the string (which is a field in my custom type) will still remain fixed. So I don't know if this whole approach will work.

```
readonly struct PinnableStruct {

  private readonly string _String;
  private readonly int _Index;

  public unsafe ref char GetPinnableReference() {
    if (_String is null) return ref Unsafe.AsRef<char>(null);
    fixed (char* p = _String) return ref Unsafe.AsRef<char>(p + _Index);
  }
}
```

The code above will then be utilized by the following sample code:

```
static void SomeRoutine(PinnableStruct data) {
  fixed(char* p = data) {
    //iterate over characters in data and do something with them
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need for fixed on the string or pointers at this point and in fact it would be conceptually incorrect to do so.  After your null check/return (which should also check for length 0), you can do this:

```
var strSpan = _String.AsSpan();
return ref strSpan[_Index];
```

This, as the function name specifies, returns a pinnable reference to the first character of the underlying string.  What you've got above returns a reference to the first dereferenced element of a pinned pointer to the underlying string, but the lifetime of the pinning is limited to the scope of the fixed statement (could be wrong, but I don't think the returned ref keeps it pinned).  Using a ref to a Span element avoids an unnecessary pinning.

Update - I looked into pinned pointers a bit more (a bunch of unfruitful google searches - fell back to decompiling/experimenting).  It turns out returning a ref to an element of a pinned pointer does not preserve the pin.  The reference returned is a reference to the resolved address - all context of pinning is lost.

I thought maybe changing `_String` to a `Memory<char>` (use `AsMemory` extension in constructor) could work.  Then your `GetPinnableReference` could just `return ref _String[0];` but `AsMemory` gives you a read-only memory object (can't return writable reference).

Short of implementing `IPinnable` with `GCHandle` and `IDisposable` or `MemoryManager<T>` (heavier than you want for sure), I think my `Span<char>` solution above might be the most safe/correct way to accomplish this.

Here's a disassembly of GetPinnableReference (don't mind my PowerPC.Test namespace - I'm making a .NET Standard 1.1 PowerPC binary disassembler/emulator/debugger and using these concepts heavily, hence my interest):

```
.method public hidebysig instance char&  GetPinnableReference() cil managed
{
  // Code size       34 (0x22)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (char* V_0,
           string pinned V_1,
           char& V_2)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarg.0
  IL_0002:  ldfld      string PowerPC.Test.Console.Program/PinnableStruct::_string
  IL_0007:  stloc.1
  IL_0008:  ldloc.1
  IL_0009:  conv.u
  IL_000a:  stloc.0
  IL_000b:  ldloc.0
  IL_000c:  brfalse.s  IL_0016
  IL_000e:  ldloc.0
  IL_000f:  call       int32 [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::get_OffsetToStringData()
  IL_0014:  add
  IL_0015:  stloc.0
  IL_0016:  nop
  IL_0017:  ldloc.0
  IL_0018:  call       !!0& [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe::AsRef<char>(void*)
  IL_001d:  stloc.2
  IL_001e:  br.s       IL_0020
  IL_0020:  ldloc.2
  IL_0021:  ret
} // end of method SomeInfo::GetPinnableReference
```

I don't expect the majority of readers to be able to read the IL, but it's ok.  The answer we seek is right at the top (and confirmed in the IL following it).  We've got three locals: `char* V_0`, `string pinned V_1`, and `char& V_2`.  To me, this sheds a bit of light on why the fixed syntax is what it is.  You have the fixed keyword represented by `string pinned V_1`, the pointer to char (from your code) represented by `char* V_0`, and the reference that gets returned represented by `char& V_2`.  Three separate concepts represented by three separate code constructs.

So, your fixed statement pins the string and assigns the pinning reference to `V_1` at `IL_0002` to `IL_0007`, then it loads `V_1` converts it to a pointer (conversion to unsigned integer) and stores it in `V_0` (your `char* p`) at `IL_0008` to `IL_000a`, finally it loads `V_0`, computes the offset of the `char` specified by `_index`, and stores it back in `V_0` at `IL_000e` to `IL_0015`.  Within the scope of the fixed statement, it loads V_0, converts it to a reference via `Unsave.AsRef<char>`, and stores it in `V_2` (the reference that will be returned) at `IL_0017` to `IL_001d`.  I'm not sure why the C# compiler does this, but the last bit from `IL_001e` to `IL_0021` is often how the compiler handles returning a value; it inserts a branch to the block that will return the value (even though in this case it's the next instruction), then it loads the return value from a local variable (that it created and IMO un-necessarily assigned to, but perhaps there is a logical explanation for this?), and finally returns the result you had obtained several instructions ago.

There you have it, an answer, finally!  The pinning from your fixed statement can't be maintained because it's dereferencing an unmanaged pointer `V_0`/`p` that just happens in this case to be backed by a pinning reference, `V_1`, which is something the instructions to dereference the pointer don't know about).  The CLR team could've been clever in the JIT and handled that case specially through analysis by associating the char reference with the pinned reference, but I think that'd be architecturally weird, hard to explain/document, and I doubt they went that route, so I didn't go look at the CLR code to verify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! "but the lifetime of the pinning is limited to the scope of the fixed statement (could be wrong, but I don't think the returned ref keeps it pinned)" - that was in essence my question, would be really nice to know how `fixed` behaves with `ref return`s.

Comment: Your implementation is interesting! However, I am concerned that this will be slower than the unsafe code above. Plus, my main use case was to loop over the chars in a substring, starting at the returned char, and ending with the last character of the substring. So, in the actual case I will be returning not `p` but rather `p + n`, i.e. won't start at the beginning of the string, and then examine _m_ more characters (length of the substring).

Comment: I have elaborated on my question a bit more so the intent is more clear.

Comment: Just a thought, but you could instead have a `DoStuff(CharPtrAction action)` on your object that this guy calls with your fixed pointer (where `CharPtrAction' is a delegate taking a `char*`).

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed examination! I guess I will need to go the `AsSpan()` route, even though it looks like it will be slower. However I am still unsure if your approach is correct, because even though you are using `Span<char>` to obtain a reference to a specific char within a string, you are then returning that char by ref, exiting the function, and thus "throwing away the span", making the backing string (as I understand it) once again unpinned and movable, which makes the returned reference to a char potentially invalid as well.

Comment: Thanks for an interesting suggestion with delegates! I would love to do something like this if it was not for the speed, and delegates are heavy!

Comment: In the Span based approach, you're not pinning until your fixed statement.  What you return is a managed reference to an element of the string (not pinned/can move, but is "pinnable" because it's a reference to managed).  As for Span being slower, curious to see by how much.  It's a small stack-only struct (readonly ref struct) holding a reference to a range within something else (the string).  It's supposed to be just slightly less performant than direct array access and the only use of it here is to get a reference to one element that can be pinned for faster access.

Comment: For the delegate approach, delegate construction is slow enough to avoid in a function of this nature, but a call to a delegate is on the order of a virtual call.  If you make the worker method static and pass pointer, refs to instance fields to be set, and any extra data needed, it could be pretty fast (though perhaps not as fast as it could be).

Comment: By static, I also mean static readonly delegate constructed in class initialize

Comment: One more thought/idea depending on whether or not you ever need to box this struct would be to make it a read-only ref struct holding `Span<char> _String`, and `int _Index` along with any other data your PinnableStruct is supposed to hold.  Any `PinnableStruct` parameter should be marked `in` for efficiency.

Comment: A big you're welcome/thanks for the ask to you.  I'm also trying to wrap my head around these new concepts and this simple (but oh so complex) question has made for a good learning experience.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and ideas! I guess what I still don't get about the `Span<T>` is how can "return[ing] a managed reference to an element of the string" be safe, when the string is _not_ pinned? AFter all, the string can be moved by the GC, and therefore the returned `ref char` (a typed-pointer in disguise) be no longer valid. Or is it that if/when the underlying string gets moved, the ref is also updated so it points to the new location of the string (+ offset)? If so, it would be nice to see some docs that clearly explain it. Otherwise it looks the same as if returning `char*`.

Comment: Making it a `ref struct` would be great, except that it is not _only_ boxing/unboxing that is the concern. Generics too. `ref struct`s cannot be used as type-parameters at present. This, together with their inability to implement interfaces is a serious limitation, thus I end up almost never making `ref` structs.

Comment: Limitations on ref structs currently do suck.  Sounds like a deal breaker.  As for ref, it's not a pointer it's a reference (kind of like a handle, might actually be a pointer that gets updated, but I'm not sure).  What I do know that as long as one exists on a managed call stack or within an object on the heap that hasn't been collected, GC won't collect (but may move) what's been returned.  This means the ref will continue to be valid.